# Error in Z3Py code

Tags: z3, z3py

Whats wrong with the following script http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Cbl? 
Adding the last two lines  gives me the following error `'instancemethod' object is not #subscriptable`

```
x,t,t1,t2,x_next=Reals ('x t t1 t2 x_next')
location,location_next=Bools('location location_next')
x=0
location=BoolVal(False)
k=20
for i in range(k):
 s=Solver()
 s.add(Or(And(x_next-x>=2*t,x_next-x<=3*t,x_next<=12,t>0,Not(location)),
         And(x_next-x>=-2*t,x_next-x<=-t,x_next>=0,t>0,location)),location_next==If(And(Not(location),x_next>=12),True,If(And(location,x_next<=0),False,location)))

print s.check()
print s.model()
m=s.model
#x=m[x_next]
#location=m[location_next]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m=s.model` assigns a function to `m`.  I believe you meant to assign the result of calling `s.model`, so include parenthesis to make the call:

```
m=s.model()
```

Comment: @Leonardo de Moura:  Thanks for the typo fix.